# Laravel inertia vue3 - Unable to locate file in Vite manifest: resources/js/Pages/Home.vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vite, shared-hosting

On my local, using "npm run dev" I can correctly compile the resource folders, but when I deploy on a shared server, I cannot access the command line afterwards, even after executing the "npm run build" command and creating the file manifest, I get this error:

@vite(['resources/js/app.js', "resources/js/Pages/{$page['component']}.vue"])

This is what I have in my manifest.json file:

[image: Content of manifest.json]

I could not find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution that works in prod, but it breaks the npm run dev (and I cannot restore it yet).

I found something interesting in case you use a persistent layout.

I do, and I changed my app.js accordingly. If I revert it, the Vite error disappears, but no persistent layout, which is a no-go, of course.

Before (no vite error):

```
createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')),
```

After:

```
createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: name => {
        const pages = import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue', {eager: true});
        let page = pages[`./Pages/${name}.vue`];
        page.default.layout ??= AuthenticatedLayout;
        return page;
    },
```

And here is the solution-ish:

```
createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: name => {
        const page = resolvePageComponent(
            `./Pages/${name}.vue`,
            import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')
        );
        page.then((module) => {
            module.default.layout ??= AuthenticatedLayout;
        });
        return page;
    },
```

Found here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vite/vite-inertiajs-persistent-layouts

Comment: Please embrace the concept of providing an answer according to [answer]. The history of your journey is not important. So please maintain the best answre according to [answer] and drop whatever became obsolete, along with all editing history details and dead ends. You might even consider deleting this, go on with your search and when you found  satisfying solution edit and undelete again.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Things is, it is a solution for the prod environment. It breaks things in dev, but in the end, it provide a solution for OP's problem. I agree I should have paid more attention to presentation, I'll keep that in mind, thanks for friendly reminder :)